# Xcode Meanings. "window"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, window

Hello StackOverflow people :)

I have a simple question regarding Xcode (cocoa) "Apple application maker"

Q : What is the name for the transition between 2 windows?

and do I make another "file" in the resources to make another window?

Thanks!

any extra details is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The transitions are just animations most of the time, but we can add in extra effects like fading and flipping depending on the type of the new window/view that we want to load. Within Xcode, the terminology to view and see a new window is called a "push" - as you push it onto the view hierarchy. To close it, you "pop" it off the stack.

And yes, you simply make a new file and then choose it's type to make another window - depends on exactly which type you are after, whether it's a code file or interface file etc.

Hope this helps.